# Terraform Azure AD Web App wont Pass Client ID and Password to Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I have recently created and AzureAD App in Terraform but when I try to pass its client ID and Password to Key Vault as a secret, I'm just getting errors like `no resource declared in main.tf` or a weird one. `No applications found matching filter: "displayName eq` but Terraform has not even made the application yet.

see my code below

```html
# Terraform Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
  }
  #Terraform State Storage Account
  # backend "azurerm" {}
}

# Providers Block
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id     = "VALUE"
  client_id     = "VALUE"
  client_secret = "VALUE"
}

provider "random" {}
provider "time" {}

# Random String Resource

resource "random_string" "myrandom" {
  length  = 6
  number  = false
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  object_id = "VALUE" // This will need changing per tenant used for KeyVault
}

data "azuread_user" "user" {
  user_principal_name = "J.smith@company.com"
}

data "azuread_group" "Classroom_In_The_Cloud_AZ_AD_Group" {
  display_name     = "companyadgroup"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "Terraform_Testings" {
  #depends_on = [
  # azurerm_storage_container.website_tftestingwebsiteinstaller_account
  #]
  name                       = "cicterraformtesting"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform_Testing.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform_Testing.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_testings_client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azuread_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_AZ_AD_Group.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_testings_service_principal" { // This is for the Service Principal in the pipeline to be able to make changes to Key Vault. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}



resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "WebsiteStorageConnectionString" { // Dont use dempends on, on key vault secrets gets itself in a mess
  name  = "WebsiteStorageConnectionString"
  value = azurerm_storage_account.website_tftestwebinstaller_account.primary_access_key
  #value        = "szechuan"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
    azurerm_storage_account.website_tftestwebinstaller_account,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "WebsiteSignalRConnectionString" { // Dont use dempends on, on key vault secrets gets itself in a mess
  name         = "WebsiteSignalRConnectionString"
  value        = format("Endpoint=https://${azurerm_signalr_service.websitesignalr.name}.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=${azurerm_signalr_service.websitesignalr.primary_access_key};Version=1.0;")
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
    azurerm_signalr_service.websitesignalr,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADClientID" {
  name         = "AzureADClientID"
  value        = data.azuread_application.websiteadapp.id 
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
    azureread_application.websiteadapp,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADAppPassword" {
  name         = "AzureADAppPassword"
  value        = data.azuread_application.websiteadapp.object_id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
    azuread_application_password.websiteadapp,
  ]

}

resource "azuread_application" "websiteadapp" {
  display_name = var.adapplication_name
  #identifier_uris  = ["api://example-app"]
  owners           = [data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "VALUE" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "VALUE" # User.Read.All
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "VALUE" # User.ReadWrite
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
}

data "azuread_application" "websiteadapp" {
  display_name = var.adapplication_name
  depends_on = [
    azureread_application.websiteadapp,
  ]
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "websiteadapp" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.websiteadapp.object_id
}
```

I have tried removing depends on in Key Vault and the app does create if you take Key Vault out of the equitation which really has thrown me even more.

I have been on this task for two days now and I have been following the documentation set out in Terraform here link:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application#id

Answer (score 0):

I see few issues in your terraform code.

- When you create `resource "azuread_application" "websiteadapp"` you do not need `data "azuread_application" "websiteadapp"`
- You do need to specify dependencies with depends_on if you are already referencing this resource.
- I do not see resource `azurerm_storage_account.website_tftestwebinstaller_account`  that you are referencing in `azurerm_key_vault_secret`
- I do not see resource `azurerm_signalr_service.websitesignalr` that you are referencing in `azurerm_key_vault_secret`
- Resource `"azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADAppPassword"` should have `value` referencing to `azuread_application_password.websiteadapp.value`

Here is the code after refactoring:

```
# Terraform Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = ">= 3.0"
    }
  }
  #Terraform State Storage Account
  # backend "azurerm" {}
}

# Providers Block
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
provider "azuread" {
  tenant_id     = "VALUE"
  client_id     = "VALUE"
  client_secret = "VALUE"
}

provider "random" {}
provider "time" {}

# Random String Resource

resource "random_string" "myrandom" {
  length  = 6
  number  = false
  upper   = false
  special = false
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  object_id = "VALUE" // This will need changing per tenant used for KeyVault
}

data "azuread_user" "user" {
  user_principal_name = "J.smith@company.com"
}

data "azuread_group" "Classroom_In_The_Cloud_AZ_AD_Group" {
  display_name     = "companyadgroup"
  security_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "Terraform_Testings" {
  #depends_on = [
  # azurerm_storage_container.website_tftestingwebsiteinstaller_account
  #]
  name                       = "cicterraformtesting"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform_Testing.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_Terraform_Testing.name
  tenant_id                  = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                   = "premium"
  soft_delete_retention_days = 7

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_testings_client" { // This is for AD Users Logged into Azure to give them the right access when creating resources. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azuread_group.Classroom_In_The_Cloud_AZ_AD_Group.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "terraform_testings_service_principal" { // This is for the Service Principal in the pipeline to be able to make changes to Key Vault. 
  key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id
  tenant_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id               = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions      = ["Backup", "Delete", "Get", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Set", ]
  key_permissions         = ["Backup", "Create", "Decrypt", "Delete", "Encrypt", "Get", "Import", "List", "Purge", "Recover", "Restore", "Sign", "UnwrapKey", "Update", "Verify", "WrapKey", ]
  storage_permissions     = ["Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge", "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update", ]
  certificate_permissions = ["create", "delete", "deleteissuers", "get", "getissuers", "import", "list", "listissuers", "managecontacts", "manageissuers", "setissuers", "update", ]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADClientID" {
  name         = "AzureADClientID"
  value        = azuread_application.websiteadapp.id 
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADAppKeyId" {
  name         = "AzureADAppPassword"
  value        = azuread_application_password.websiteadapp.key_id
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
  ]

}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "AzureADAppPassword" {
  name         = "AzureADAppPassword"
  value        = azuread_application_password.websiteadapp.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.Terraform_Testings.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_client,
    azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.terraform_testings_service_principal,
  ]

}

resource "azuread_application" "websiteadapp" {
  display_name = var.adapplication_name
  #identifier_uris  = ["api://example-app"]
  owners           = [data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "VALUE" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "VALUE" # User.Read.All
      type = "Scope"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "VALUE" # User.ReadWrite
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "websiteadapp" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.websiteadapp.object_id
}
```

Comment: 1. I added data because Key Vault would moan that the resource has not been declared in the root module adding data got rid of that.
2. I added in depends on because of the order of creation to see if that would solve my issue it doesn't. 
3. I left out the storage account code and signal r because stack overflow said I have to much code in my question
4. I have tried value and that doesn't work. 

Your answer isn't really an answer just a set of statements.

Comment: Explicitly specifying a dependency is only necessary when a resource or module relies on some other resource's behavior but doesn't access any of that resource's data in its arguments.
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html

Comment: Did you try to run the code I added?

Comment: I did and worked out where I went wrong in the docs it says to reference value which is the object id but when I tried that yesterday afternoon I got resource not defined in main. When I switched it object_id I got app already exists. I didn't try running my code this morning has I switched back object_id back to value, then it would have worked as over night its picked up that the AzureADApp had been deleted yesterday in my testing. Thanks for your help.